# Is there any way to replicate Windows 10 ctrl-alt-tab behavior in Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, windows, cinnamon, alt-tab, window-switching

For the unaware: In Windows 10, `ctrl` `alt` `tab` behaves like `alt` `tab` except the switcher pop-up remains onscreen after the shortcut keys are released. With the pop-up on-screen, it can be navigated with `tab`, the arrow keys, or the mouse.

Coming from Windows 10, my normal workflow binds `ctrl` `alt` `tab` as a macro to a side button on my mouse. Such that I can quickly switch between windows with only my mouse, keeping the cursor centred on-screen.

In my experience so far with Linux Mint Cinnamon, the default `alt` `tab` behaves exactly as in Windows, but I haven't found any equivalent to Windows' `ctrl` `alt` `tab`.

Any solutions would be appreciated, I'm open to suggestions pointing to custom tools or different DEs.

Comment: I have this in KDE. (As best I can tell from the description): I can press the key combo, then click a thumb nail, to select the window.

Comment: Are you able to press and release the key combo and have the task switcher pop-up remain on screen? If so, can you please share your configuration?

Comment: I have to keep hold of the modifier key. I also found a toggle present windows: workspace →shortcuts →kwin→toggle present windows. It can be bound to any modifier + key. it presents all windows, for you to click on.